# Why are the results obtained by using the spark's QuantileDiscretizer grouped unevenly?

Tags: apache-spark, split, apache-spark-ml, quantile, discretization

I have a Dataset.

The feature columns are grouped using the `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.QuantileDiscretizer` class of spark 2.3.1, and the resulting model grouping results are not uniform.

The data reflected in the last packet is almost twice as much as the other packets, and I set 11 packets in the parameter, but only 10 packets are actually obtained.

Look at the program below.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.QuantileDiscretizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer
val model = new QuantileDiscretizer()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("level")
    .setNumBuckets(11)
    .setHandleInvalid("keep")
    .fit(df)
println(model.getSplits.mkString(", "))
model
    .transform(df)
    .groupBy("level")
    .count
    .orderBy("level")
    .show
```

The output:

```
-Infinity, 115.0, 280.25, 479.75, 712.5, 1000.0, 1383.37, 1892.75, 2690.93, 4305.0, Infinity
+-----+------+                                                                  
|level| count|
+-----+------+
| null|  9113|
|  0.0| 55477|
|  1.0| 52725|
|  2.0| 54657|
|  3.0| 53592|
|  4.0| 54165|
|  5.0| 54732|
|  6.0| 52915|
|  7.0| 54090|
|  8.0| 53393|
|  9.0|107369|
+-----+------+
```

Grouping the last set of data separately:

```
val df1 = df.where("features >= 4305.0")
val model1 = new QuantileDiscretizer()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("level")
    .setNumBuckets(2)
    .setHandleInvalid("keep")
    .fit(df1)

println(model1.getSplits.mkString(", "))
model1
    .transform(df1)
    .groupBy("level")
    .count
    .orderBy("level")
    .show
```

The output:

```
-Infinity, 20546.12, Infinity
+-----+-----+                                                                   
|level|count|
+-----+-----+
|  0.0|53832|
|  1.0|53537|
+-----+-----+
```

If I manually specify the grouper boundaries to group:

```
val splits = Array(Double.NegativeInfinity, 
    115.0, 280.25, 479.75, 712.5, 1000.0, 1383.37, 1892.75, 2690.93, 4305.0, 
    20546.12, Double.PositiveInfinity)
val model = new Bucketizer()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("level")
    .setHandleInvalid("keep")
    .setSplits(splits)
model
.transform(df)
.groupBy("level")
.count
.orderBy("level")
.show
```

The output:

```
+-----+-----+                                                                   
|level|count|
+-----+-----+
| null| 9113|
|  0.0|55477|
|  1.0|52725|
|  2.0|54657|
|  3.0|53592|
|  4.0|54165|
|  5.0|54732|
|  6.0|52915|
|  7.0|54090|
|  8.0|53393|
|  9.0|53832|
| 10.0|53537|
+-----+-----+
```

Please tell me why `QuantileDiscretizer` will behave like this?

What if I want to group the raw data evenly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the relative error to a small number, e.g.,

```
qds = QuantileDiscretizer(
    numBuckets=10, 
    inputCol="score_rand",
    outputCol="buckets", 
    relativeError=0.0001, 
    handleInvalid="error")
```

I believe that if you still do not obtain almost even groups it is because there are ties within your bucketed column. Then try and add a small random number, larger than the relative error, and you should get the desired number of buckets.